# Connecting with RDS using internal hosted zone

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-rds, amazon-route53

I have two  VPC's one for RDS and another for EKS cluster in one account and I have Route53 config in root account, VPC pairing is enabled to connect all the VPC.
I can connect with the rds using direct endpoint but when I am using the private internal hosted zone then I get the below error

`ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'dbname.database.internal' (2)`

I want my application to point RDS using private hosted zone,
I have DNS hostname and DNS resolution enabled
I have VPC enabled
Sg of RDS is allowing traffic.

Any help what I would be missing would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, a private hosted zone is associated with a single VPC. You get `Unknown MySQL server host` error because only the RDS VPC knows how to resolve the 'dbname.database.internal' DNS. You need to **associate** the EKS VPC with the private hosted zone:

> 1. Sign in to the AWS Management Console and open the Route 53 console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/route53/.
> 2. In the navigation pane, choose Hosted zones.
> 3. Choose the radio button for the private hosted zone that you want to associate more VPCs with.
> 4. Choose Edit.
> 5. Choose Add VPC.
> 6. Choose the Region and the ID of the VPC that you want to associate with this hosted zone.
> 7. To associate more VPCs with this hosted zone, repeat steps 5 and 6.
> 8. Choose Save changes.

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/hosted-zone-private-associate-vpcs.html